# Is there a way to make URL parameter in MapRoute being take into account in ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I built an web application where the `RouteConfig.cs` was the default one.

Now I received a task where I need to append a customer tracking ID in the beginning of the URL but keeping the same functionality it has when it is not present too.

> http://localhost:60202/Home/Index //Generic customer
>   http://localhost:60202/Location/123/Home/Index //URL with the customer tracking id

This code `123` is a tracking ID where my customer knows the location he originates the call to my page. I have no power to ask them to change this since they use across the globe.

I tried to achieve this with this custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Route",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);


routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "Location/{trackingId}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { trackingId = 0, controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

In this case I can access my application with both URL schema I provided above but I couldn't manage to make `ActionLink` and `BeginForm` take this into account.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home") //this should have full URL info
```

Is there a way to achieve this without the need to change every `ActionLink`, `Url.Content` and `BeginForm` and surround them with `if` in every case?

How could I use both URL schema without change every navigation code?

Our currently implemented approach is to duplicated the folders in **IIS** since there is only 4 as of today but in near future it can be a pain to maintain.

I don't know why but based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496740/asp-net-mvc-one-way-route) question it should work out of the box.

**Edit 1**

Looks like changing position of these two `MapRoute` are making the `ActionLink` work as I expected. Unfortunately `Url.Content` still is buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's embarrassing but looks like the order you add routes make difference. So I changed to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "Location/{trackingId}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { trackingId = 0, controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Route",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this change every `ActionLink` started to work as I expected. I still had the problem with `Url.Content` I was using in Ajax calls.

In this case I figured out that I should use `Ulr.Action` for this instead.

Referenced `js` and `css` still used the second `MapRoute` (or don't even care about the route at all) but this is not a problem.